# Linked existing b2c tenant to my azure subscription but not able to create resource?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Getting error **You are currently signed into the 'Azure AD B2C tenant' directory which does not have any subscriptions.** when I try to create a resource in Azure AD B2C.

Please help I am new to Azure

Comment: What do you mean by "create a resource in Azure AD B2C"?  AD B2C is usually used for public users of Websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you done this ?

> The Azure subscription has a trust relationship with Azure Active
>   Directory (Azure AD), which means that the subscription trusts Azure
>   AD to authenticate users, services, and devices. **Multiple
>   subscriptions can trust the same Azure AD directory, but each
>   subscription can only trust a single directory**.

Following link might help (check To associate an existing subscription to your Azure AD directory)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory

Answer (score 6):

Switch back to the directory where you have your subscription and create the resources there.

Don't take my answer as definitive, since I'm still a newbie, but at this point my understanding is this: B2C needs a new tenant because of the way it is designed (it isn't just an add-on for AD) and you link it to your subscription for billing purposes. But that's it. You don't need to create the resources for your app there, although I guess you could do it if you get a new subscription or transfer another one.

I already created a mobile app in my default tenant and successfully used the linked B2C tenant for authentication and I guess you've done that already. But since this was one of the few results that I got when I googled the message you quoted, I think it's worth sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD B2C needs a Microsoft Azure Subscription for billing purposes. You're going to need 3 things to make that message go away:

1. Azure AD Tenant
2. MS Azure Subscription
3. Associate your Azure AD B2C tenant to the MS Azure Subscription

It's a bit strange as Azure AD B2C tenants feel very similar to Azure AD (and run on a lot of the the same infrastructure behind the scenes) ... but from a billing standpoint, they are almost treated like MS Azure resources (e.g. VM, App Service, etc)